# Reshape dataframe wide to long format

Tags: r, reshape, long-format-data, wide-format-data

I have a dataframe including around 2500 obs. of 500 variables. Here is the example:
[image: wide format]

And here is what I want:
[image: long format]

I would like to convert wide format to long format like the image above.

Is there a way to convert asset, liabilities, equality, etc. at once?

I succeeded in converting only `asset` to long format by referring to these sites:

http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/

[reshape dataframe from wide to long in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72137641/reshape-dataframe-from-wide-to-long-in-r)

But I don't know how to convert several variables at once.

Comment: `df %>% tidyr::pivot_longer(!company, names_to = c("year", ".value"), names_sep = "_")`. See [Reshaping multiple sets of measurement columns (wide format) into single columns (long format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12466493/reshaping-multiple-sets-of-measurement-columns-wide-format-into-single-columns)

Comment: What about the post that you linked to didn't work? The formatting and operation are almost exactly the same